# Python: Error in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-error-1054

```
import MySQLdb    
import random

db = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "python-test", passwd = "python", db = "python-test")

cursor = db.cursor()

var = .3

sql = "INSERT INTO RandomInt 
         (RAND) 
       VALUES 
         (var)" # RandomInt is the name of the table and Rand is the Column Name

cursor.execute(sql)

db.commit()
db.close()
```

I get an error saying `Operational Error: (1054, "Unknown column 'var' in 'field list'")` Why do I get this error and how do I fix this although I have already defined var?

Comment: To python that SQL is just a string. This has been pointed out in the answers of course, but it's not going to replace the 'var' in your string unless you do tell it to.

Answer (score 5):

As written, `var` is being sent to MySQL as a string.
Give this a shot instead:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO RandomInt (RAND) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.execute(sql, (var,))
```

Edit:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> MySQLdb.paramstyle
'format'
```

MySQLdb's paramstyle is `format`; which, according to the [DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) is `%s`:

> ```
>             'format'        ANSI C printf format codes, 
>                             e.g. '...WHERE name=%s'
> ```

Comment: cursor.execute is definitely better.  Doesn't it take "?" for parameters though?  or is the "%s" also acceptable?

Comment: @ars: added background info regarding `paramstyle`.

Answer (score 1):

This will fix one issue:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO RandomInt (RAND) VALUES (%s)" 
cursors.execute(sql, (var,))
```

What remains is the name of the table where you write into, 0.3 is not an int.

Edit: paramstyle of mysqldb is `%s` not `?`.

Comment: I think ? should be %s. Depends on the `paramstyle`.

Comment: cursors.execute(sql, var)
(1) multiple cursors ?-)
(2) 2nd arg should be a tuple `(var, )`

Answer (score 1):

```
var = .3
sql = "INSERT INTO RandomInt (RAND) VALUES (%s)" 
cursor.execute(sql, (var,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql appears to MySQL as:

```
INSERT INTO RandomInt (RAND) VALUES (var)
```

To actually have the string substitute var, try this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO RandomInt (RAND) VALUES (%d)"  % (var,)
```

Now, MySQL should see:

```
INSERT INTO RandomInt (RAND) VALUES (0.3)
```

NOTE: Adam Bernier is right about sql injection.  See the [cursor.execute](http://pythonweb.org/projects/webmodules/doc/0.5.3/html_multipage/lib/node40.html) doc for parameter substitution as well as his answer.

Comment: +1; beat me. Nitpicks: 1) vulnerable to SQL-injection, and 2) the `%d` should be `%s`.

Comment: -1 vulnerable to SQL-injection, SQL has to be retranslated each time if being done in a loop ... there's rarely a good reason to do it this way and pushing it at a beginner without any remarks at all is disgraceful.

Comment: John: Huh?  That's why I added the remark at the end and pointed to Adam's answer.  The timestamp shows it was ~3 minutes before your comment.

Comment: I type slowly / I got a cup of copy / whatever. So what? The fact that you changed your answer is irrelevant; you shouldn't have contemplated such an answer in the first place.